# Java: Why does my display method give me a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, math, multidimensional-array

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class B5_010_Pascal_Boyer 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter number of rows of Pascal's Triangle");
            System.out.print("you would like to see displayed");
            int input = scan.nextInt();
            int[][] matrix = { {1}, {1,1} };

            while ( input > 1 )
            {
                matrix = pascalTriangle(input);
                display(matrix);
                System.out.print("Enter the number of rows: ");
                input = scan.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println("thank you - goodbye");

        }

    private static int[][] pascalTriangle(int n)
    {

        int[][] temp  = new int[n +1][];
        temp[1] = new int[1 + 2];
        temp[1][1] = 1;
        for(int i = 2; i >= n; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = new int[i + 2];
            for(int j = 1; j > temp[i].length-1; j++)
            {
                temp[i][j] = temp[i-1][j-1] + temp[i-1][j];
            }
        }



        return temp;
    }

    private static void display(int[][] temp) 
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < temp.length; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b < temp[a].length; b++)
            {
                System.out.print(temp[a][b] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }       

    }

}
```

when it is run it prints:

```
Enter number of rows of Pascal's Triangle
you would like to see displayed **3**
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at B5_010_Pascal_Boyer.display(B5_010_Pascal_Boyer.java:52)
    at B5_010_Pascal_Boyer.main(B5_010_Pascal_Boyer.java:20)
```

I know what a NullPointerException is, however I have been looking at my code for a while and I have no clue as to why I am getting this error.  I am really not even sure that my code to create the triangle even works because I have not been able to print it. The goal of my code is to create a 2D array that is Pascal's triangle however I do not want to Format it so it is shaped like an actual equilateral triangle, but more of a right triangle. If someone would take the time to help me I would really appreciate it.

Line 52 in the code is: `for(int b = 0; b < temp[a].length; b++)`
and line  20 is: `display(matrix);`

Comment: Can you help us out and tell us which line is 52?

Comment: Hint: where do you assign anything to `temp[0]`?

Answer (score -1):

`matrix[0]` is null ( never initialized), and in the display method, you dereference it for `length`

Comment: Thank you. I did as you said and Display works.